# Mimic native scrolling using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ios, webkit

Which Javascript libraries can be used to mimic the native scrolling behavior on an IOS device (mainky iPad) Even jQuery based libraries would be fine.

Also before u say, I know the most common is iScroll https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll
But i want to know more...

Please list as many as you could. Thank u.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Scrollability](http://joehewitt.github.com/scrollability/) by Joe Hewitt is a recently-developed implementation that does a pretty good job of mimicking the native scrolling on iOS devices. However, it is by his own admission a "work-in-progress" and not ready for production use.

Additionally, iOS 5 will have direct native scrolling support via the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` CSS property and value.  Setting that along with `overflow: scroll` on an element will make scrolling behave like scrolling a panel in a native app: one finger, native-style momentum and behavior. Basically everything that takes a good chunk of JavaScript can be replaced with two CSS properties.

The downside is that since it is only in the iOS beta, you still have to use a script as a fallback until iOS 5 is *mainstream* (not just released), Android adopts it (and that release becomes mainstream), etc.  We will need a fallback for a good while yet.

You can get more details at [FunctionSource](http://functionsource.com/post/scrollability-can-hopefully-become-a-shim) and [this blog](http://johanbrook.com/browsers/native-momentum-scrolling-ios-5/).  Again, this isn't of use today but will be useful in the next 6 to 12 months (possibly longer for other platforms).

Comment: Thx a lot for your reply.. Just one question though....When u say iOS 5 will have direct native scrolling support via the -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch CSS property .....what exactly does it mean ? Does it mean like we can just apply that property to any element e.g. a div of fixed height...If yes, we anyways get fixed height divs to scroll on IOS devices with 2-fingers even now...Could you please elaborate on that part...as i think IOS5 is not very far...

Comment: but scrollability make the page "bounce" (you can see the grey stuff under the webview when on safari mobile). which does not seem native

Answer (score 4):

So IOS 5 webkit now has native scrolling.  But it's still got some issues, especially if you're trying to get an "app" feel.

Using this CSS activates the native scrolling.

```
.scrollme {
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
   overflow:auto;
}
```

The problem is, if you drag downward when the div is already at the "top" of its container, you end up with the whole html document scroll-bouncing, which can expose the browser chrome when you didn't want it to.  However, there's a pure CSS a workaround (no javascript).  You can use a set of 3 nested divs.  With the outer 2 set to "scrolling:touch", you can get a fairly "native" feel.

Example code here:  https://gist.github.com/1372229

Along with the "position:fixed" property, this goes a long way towards simplifying things.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting list of Touch and Touch-Scroll Javascript libraries:

https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Touch