# jquery performance of $('html, body').animate on iPad

Tags: jquery, html

I want to scroll down a webpage about 500 pixels over say 2 seconds in order to reveal new data that has just come in from an ajax call.  I've used the following snippet:

```
$('html, body').animate({'scrollTop':'+=500'}, 2000);
```

It is reasonably quick to setup on PC, but on iPad the call to animate takes about 650ms to set up.  The whole page is frozen (animated loading .gif's freeze too).  Why is it so slow? and is there anything I can do to speed up this setup call?

Comment: where have you positioned this line in your script? If you adjust it to the top or within another function this could 'speed' things up.

Comment: I found another question that might help you out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806909/mimic-native-scrolling-using-javascript

Comment: @Beneto it's more that javascript disappears into this setup call for 650ms - would moving it around in the js really help?

Comment: @MattParkins depends where it's being called. Devices are slower at complying with scripts so to structure the call within the ajax success function or previously may help. But seeing as you've mentioned the gif's freezing I'm not entirely sure :/ How large is the ajax request?

Comment: The data isn't massive - between 100 and 4000 bytes which returns between 5 and say 30 lines of html.  I wonder what happens if I start it scrolling while it is away AJAXing but before there is space to scroll into?  Will it just ignore the call?  Or perhaps I could extend the height of the document artificially before the data returns - not sure how much data will be returned though until it is back though.

Comment: Ok, that's not too bad - I've started the scrolling early while the AJAX call is away with the fairies.